# Incorrect return type for lodash.minBy when input array is not empty

Tags: typescript, lodash

I raised this issue for lodash, however I think at this time it might not a bug, but the lack of functionality of typescript, any suggestion here?

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5586

I am trying to use the minBy function from lodash with TypeScript and I have noticed that the return type is T | undefined, however, when the input array is not empty, I expect the function to always return a value of type T

```
interface SomType {
  value: number
}

const array: SomeType[] = [{ value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }]

const minValue = _.minBy(array, 'value')

console.log(minValue) // { value: 2 }

// TypeScript infers the type of `minValue` as `SomeType | undefined`
// but I expect it to be `SomeType` since the input array is not empty
```

I would appreciate if the function could have the correct return type when the input array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash types are managed separately, see on [DefinitelyTyped/types/lodash](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/lodash).

In particular [`minBy`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ad92f28c658f72c74f21bf50213480d18f37b412/types/lodash/common/math.d.ts#L235-L255):

```
minBy<T>(
  collection: List<T> | null | undefined,
  iteratee?: ValueIteratee<T>
): T | undefined;
```

---

Unfortunately, TypeScript has no way to know whether an *array* is empty or not.

It would probably be possible to build a wrapper function that can return a non-undefined type when a non-empty *tuple* is passed in, but that would force you to have such tuple in the first place.